# How do scientists calculate the orbital period of a planet?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics, parallax

It is known that you can calculate the distance to a planet using parallax, but how do scientists calculate the orbital period of a planet?

(Assuming they don't know the distance and can't use Kepler's law)

Comment: Wait for it to come back the same place in the sky.  I guess that we knew this about the plsnets before we knew anything else.

Comment: You mean in cases where they can’t wait long enough to get back the same conditions as before?

Comment: @badjohn but won't we also be moving? Then maybe the results can vary?

Comment: If we figure out our own movement first then we can adjust for that.  We need to assume that the stars are stationary but that still allows a very good approximation.

Comment: Planets where? Those in our solar system or others?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to calculate orbital period of a planet is by taking the time difference between two moments at which it is observed to be in the same place in the sky.

$P = t_2 - t_1$

where

- $P$ is the orbital period,
- $t_1$ is the time at which it is observed at a certain place in the sky,
- and $t_2$ is the next time at which it is observed at the same place in the sky.

This is slightly complicated by the fact the observer (presumably on Earth) moves, but this can be compensated for.

The uncertainty on $P$ can be reduced by taking not one but multiple periods.

If we're in a hurry, we can also determine its path by measuring only a fraction of an orbit, and calculate its period from that.  This will increase the uncertainty of the period, but with repeated measurements this uncertainty can then again be decreased.

Answer (score 1):

I found something related to this: it was a method used by Copernicus to calculate the orbital period, assuming the orbits are circular (I will address this later). First we measure the time when the sun, earth and the planet are in the same line (in opposition). We call this $t_0$. Then we wait for the next opposition and when it happens, at say $t_1$, we find the time interval between the two oppositions: $S = t_1 - t_0$.[image]

$E$ here is the orbital period of the Earth, which we know is 1 year. We want to find the
orbital period of the planet which I will denote by $P$. Now, using some basic high school level geometry, we know that $$\frac{S - E}{E} = \frac{S}{P}$$(Think about it. It is just circles) Rearranging (again using some very basic algebra), $$\frac{1}{E} - \frac{1}{S} = \frac{1}{P}$$ And there you go! You get a formula to find out $P$. This method was first used by Copernicus in his infamous book *Des Revolutionibus*.

The orbits of the planets are not entirely circular: they were discovered to be elliptical by Kepler; but again, as the question assumed that we don't know Kepler's laws, we don't know that they are elliptic (Kepler's 1st law). But, even then, this provides us with a good approximate.